# How to deploy a c# application on Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, azure

I have a simple calculator written in C# with WFP, and I want to push it into Windows Azure so other people could run the application. I've looked at the MSDN website and it does not say anything about how to link the project that I have in my computer to the cloud on Microsoft Windows Azure. Can anyone please guide me on how to do it ? or link me to a website that does ? Thank you very much.

PS: I'm totally new to Windows Azure, and I just know it like a week ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy"? *run* it there or *install* it from there? Do you mean you want your app in the app-store?

Comment: When you say you were "looking all over the Internet," did you spend any time at [Azure.com](http://azure.microsoft.com)? Great documentation there. Also: Please edit to clarify your question: Are you trying to install your own app into an Azure VM for your own use, or are you trying to set it up for distribution, so that others may install it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its says you can't unless you deploy your app using Click Once deployment.
Try to rea this  [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0b576707-3756-4f4c-8bbf-f026f17be5bd/wpf-applications-deployed-on-window-azure?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)

and this [article](http://elbruno.com/2013/06/01/azure-howto-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-and-azure-website/) for How to deploy using click once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of the question. This answer has nothing to do with Azure.

Comment: have you seen the first link sir?

Comment: Well... now we get into ambiguity. Re-reading the OP's question, it's impossible to tell if he wants to actually install the app into an Azure VM, or push the app to Azure for the purposes of deployment (and I interpreted it as the latter).